# Does Mac OS X 10.8+ support self-signed Package Installer

Tags: certificates, macos

I'm not sure whether self-signed **Package Installer** are supported by Mac OS X 10.8+

Using informations in [How to create an Apple Installer Package Signing Certificate](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/17909/how-to-create-an-apple-installer-package-signing-certificate) I could create a Package Installer self-signed certificate.

But all (flat) pkg files I've tried to sign with this certificate are rejected by `spctl --assess --type install`.

I've tried with packages produced by PackageMaker and `pkgbuild`, and signing them with `productsign -s`, `pkgbuild --sign` and `productbuild --sign`.

Using `pkgutil --check-signature`, the resulting pkg files seems actually signed:

`Package "test.pkg":
   Status: signed by a certificate trusted for current user
   Certificate Chain:
    1. com.xxx.yyy
       SHA1 fingerprint: FE 39 1E 69 C1 DC E8 F8 64 2A B1 C3 09 B7 27 94 2B 01 99 28`

But is rejected by `spctl --assess --type install`:

`test.pkg: rejected
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>assessment:authority</key>
    <dict/>
    <key>assessment:remote</key>
    <true/>
    <key>assessment:verdict</key>
    <false/>
</dict>
</plist>`

which means (AFAIK) that any GateKeeper enabled system will refuse to install the it.

I'm probably missing an obvious requirement, but I can't figure it out.

Or, simply said, 10.8+ (I'm testing on 10.9) does not support self-signed *installers* anymore ?

I would appreciate any clue or pointer (I've red the Code Signing documentation, but I may misunderstand it).

Thanks.